# get tracks from spotify playlist in R

Tags: r, api, spotify

How can I get all the tracks from a spotify playlist in r?

this is what i tried but it doesnt work

```
    response = POST(
      'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
      accept_json(),
      authenticate(clientID, secret),
      body = list(grant_type = 'client_credentials'),
      encode = 'form',
      verbose()
    )
    
    token = content(response)$access_token
    authorization.header = paste0("Bearer ", token)
    
    #Get track info#
    call1 <- GET(url = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/{53Y8wT46QIMz5H4WQ8O22c}", config = add_headers(authorization = authorization.header))
    call1
```

Comment: There are R packages to access Sotify's API, see  [Rspotify](https://r-music.rbind.io/posts/2018-10-01-rspotify/) or this [R-bloggers post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2016/09/my-new-r-package/). With curl, see [here](https://martijnvanvreeden.nl/collecting-spotify-data-with-r/). Also, there was a package `spotifyr` that was [removed from CRAN](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=spotifyr).

Comment: You'll also have to obtain ```clientID``` and ```secret``` tokens by making an account (as the first linked post in the above comment describes). Then, just replace the ```clientID``` and ```secret``` variables in your code with those tokens.